Faster alternative to apply() for operations on multiple matrices/images
Say I have a bunch of image slices as a 3D array:
myImages = array(runif(1024*1024*100), dim = c(1024,1024,100))

and want the pixel-wise median value.
medianImage = apply(myImages, c(1,2), median)

This process takes quite some time. Is there a faster alternative in R?

Rfast::rowMedians is much faster, but it requires reshaping myImages:
myImages <- array(runif(1024*1024*100), dim = c(1024,1024,100))
system.time(medianImage <- apply(myImages, c(1,2), median))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   38.93    1.03   40.01
system.time({
  dm <- dim(myImages)
  dim(myImages) <- c(prod(dm[1:2]), dm[3])
  medianImage2 <- `dim<-`(Rfast::rowMedians(myImages), dm[1:2])
  dim(myImages) <- dm
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.58    0.29    1.86
all.equal(medianImage, medianImage2)
#> [1] TRUE

Compare to matrixStats::rowMedians.
dim(myImages) <- c(prod(dm[1:2]), dm[3])

bench::mark(
  Rfast = Rfast::rowMedians(myImages),
  matrixStats = matrixStats::rowMedians(myImages),
  min_iterations = 10
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 Rfast          1.23s    1.23s     0.806       8MB        0
#> 2 matrixStats    1.63s    1.64s     0.610    8.17MB        0


It's reassuring that I’m not alone in encountering issues with Rfast; it seems to be a common experience. Further reinforcing my decision to use matrixStats, which has proven to be more reliable and consistent for my needs, it's also widely used in Bioconductor.

@jay.sf, I have seen examples where {Rfast} outperforms {matrixstats} by resonable amounts and, therefore, see reasons to recommend {Rfast}.

@Friede Note that the discussion was about recurring bugs in Rfast, not just performance speed. I prioritize reliability over minimal speed advantages in tools.

@jay.sf, as I noted I have seen comparisons where speed advantaegs are not minimal.

@jblood94 Thanks for the answer. I have just one question: can you explain  dim<-  ? That syntax looks kinda foreign to me.

\dim<-`is a function. When called as`dim<-`(x, d), it assigns the vector das the dimensions of the objectxand then returns the redimensioned object. I could have accomplished the same thing with two lines:medianImage2 <- Rfast::rowMedians(myImages); dim(medianImage2) <- dm[1:2]`

@jblood94 thank you! the naming of the function threw me off.
